# ld: unknown option: -Ttext on Mac OS X maverick

Tags: c, linker, command, ld

I am trying to run this command

```
ld -Ttext 0x1000 -o kernel.bin loader.o main.o video.o
```

but it returns `ld: unknown option: -Ttext`

Is there any alternatives to this action or a way to make ld work?

Here is written, that option -Ttext exists, but in my case it shows that no
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ld.htm

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve?

Comment: @constantius I am following this tutorial. If I understand correctly, this command linked three *.o files into one kernel.bin  https://code.google.com/p/onyxkernel/wiki/FirstStep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"-Ttext" is where in memory the text(code) segment will be.  The macintosh ld does not support that option.  It does support "-segaddr text"(it might not be text, though, it might be _text or __text).  If you are writing an operating system, you probably want a separate toolchain because the macintosh toolchain is only designed for mach-o objects for use on the macintosh.

Answer (score -2):

`ld`'s `man` page says:

```
   -T scriptfile
   --script=scriptfile
       Use scriptfile as the linker script.  This script replaces ld's
       default linker script (rather than adding to it), so commandfile
       must specify everything necessary to describe the output file.
       If scriptfile does not exist in the current directory, "ld" looks
       for it in the directories specified by any preceding -L options.
       Multiple -T options accumulate.
```

So you should

1. Use the correct format: `ld -T text 0x1000 -o kernel.bin loader.o main.o video.o`
2. Make sure `text` exists in the current directory and is indeed a linker script.

Comment: here is written that option -Ttext exists, and my command is correct
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ld.htm

Comment: @RomaBugaian there's a space between `-T` and `scriptfile` in the example.